# Prove That $1/\sin(i \pi/n)+1/\sin(j \pi/n) \ne 2$ When $n$ is Odd

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry

The original problem is: Prove that $1/\sin(i \pi/n)+1/\sin(j \pi/n) \ne 2$ when $n$ is odd.

I tried, and found that although everything looks similar, I actually know nothing about this kind of problem. Even whether $\sin(i \pi/n)+\sin(j \pi/n)$ would equal to $1/2$ or something.

It looks like algebraic number theory, but every rational number is in all number fields, so I don't know how to make the problem fit into this framework.

So my problem is:

1. How to Solve the Original Problem?
2. What values can $\sum_n a_i\sin(i \pi/n)$ express ($a_i,i,n\in \mathbb{Z}$) (This one is somewhat vague)?
3. Is there any general idea behind these problems?

Comment: Hi Ash - could you tell me where this problem was sourced from?

Comment: @JohnM, I saw it here http://tieba.baidu.com/p/2537555764